# Is there a way to manage QLogic fiber switches on Windows 10 using a GUI?

Tags: windows-10, configuration-management, fiber, qlogic

I am trying to manage our two QLogic SANBox 5800v fiber switches from my Windows 10 workstation.

Unfortunately, due to I think Java and IE compatibility issues, the web UI does not work on a Windows 10 machine. Firstly you have to jump through hoops with compatibility mode, trusted sites and Java security settings, but using the latest build of Java I just get a Java exception (Access denied) message.

Currently the only way for me to manage these switches using a GUI, is from an old Vista PC with an outdated version of IE and Java, and this is obviously less than ideal. SANSurfer is also now deprecated, and I can't get that to run on Windows 10 either anyway.

QLogic cannot tell me how to manage via Windows 10 using a GUI, and suggest I just use the CLI. This involves having to learn commands and syntax etc. which I am wary about as I have no proper training in QLogic CLI management, and will likely end up doing something that brings down the live switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably update your QLogic SANBox [5800v firmware](http://driverdownloads.qlogic.com/QLogicDriverDownloads_UI/SearchByProd.aspx?ProductCategory=41&Product=1045&ProductName=SANbox%205800V). Check your firmware version:

- From the GUI, namely QuickTools: Switch Data Window > *Firmware* group > Firmware Version.
- From CLI: `SANbox #> show version`, look for entry `ActiveSWVersion`.

According to the [Readme for Switch Firmware 8.0.14.19.00](http://filedownloads.qlogic.com/files/Software/92292/readme_firmware_8.0.14.19.pdf), QuickTools is compatible with Java 8 on Internet Explorer 9 and later (while e.g. firmware V 7.4 was compatible with Java 2 Standard Edition Runtime Environment 1.4.2). On Windows 10, make sure you are using Internet Explorer, not Edge.

Comment: Looks like the answer to me! We are two versions behind the latest firmware (Currently running 8.0.13.16.0), but that was from 4 years ago! Will try an update and see how we get on! Thanks.